# adding percentage to a value in an input field using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a percentage to a value (number) that is in an input field.

is this possible using javascript?

this is what i came up with but it doesn't do anything.

```
        <script language="javascript">
function multiply() {
    var ans = (document.form.myNumber.value) + ("3.5%"),

        total = Math.round(ans*100)/100;

    document.form.sum_total.value = total;
}

</script>
```

please let me know if this question is not suitable for this website and i will delete it.

Thanks

EDIT:

So far i have tried everything and nothing seem to work for me.

here is what I have done so far:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myNumber").keyup(function(){
    $("#sum_total").val($(this).val());
});


       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;


          return true;
       }
</script>

<script language="javascript">
function multiply() {
var ans = parseFloat(document.form.sum_total.value);

ans = (ans * 0.035) + ans
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
        <form>
<input type="text"id="myNumber" name="myNumber" value="" onkeyup="multiply()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" ><br  /><br  />
 <input type="text" id="sum_total" readonly="true" name="sum_total" value=""> 

 <input name="perc" id="perc" type="hidden" value="3.5%" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you trying to increment the value by 3.5%?  Or add the string "3.5%" to it?

Comment: If the textbox had a value of `"12"`, `(document.form.myNumber.value) + ("3.5%"),` would result in a string of `"123.5%"`

Comment: Do you want to convert input into percentage, or just display a percentage symbol after the input. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Smeegs, i need to add the 3.5% to the value. for example 100 + 3.5%.

Comment: You have to add the text "+ 3.5%"? I would recommend using an external label when you compute the complete string

Answer (score 1):

Basic math applies here. 3.5% is actual 0.035, so parse you input value:

```
var ans = parseFloat(document.form.myNumber.value);
```

Do the math

```
ans = (ans * 0.035) + ans
```

Or multiply by 103.5%

```
ans *= 1.035
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error with your code! here is how i use it: `<script language="javascript">
function multiply() {
var ans = parseFloat(document.form.myNumber.value);

ans = (ans 0.035) + ans

}



</script>`

Comment: `ans = (ans 0.035)` -- should be `ans = (ans * 0.035)` -- missed the multiplier (I edited my answer)

Comment: everything if I'm honest. With the code above I am duplicating the value of the input field `myNumber` into another input field `sum_total`. this works as it should. now, the problem is I need to add the 3.5% to the value of `sum_total` input field. but currently i haven't been able to do that! any suggestions? am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You have to re-apply the number to that field: `document.form.myNumber.value = ans`

Comment: like this? `<script language="javascript">
function multiply() {
var ans = parseFloat(document.form.myNumber.value);

ans = (ans * 0.035) + ans

document.form.myNumber.value = ans
}

</script>`

Comment: but it doesn't though.. nothing happens to the value of the sum_total input field. it just displays the value from myNumber without adding the 3.5% ...

Comment: Ohh, use `document.getElementById("sum_total").value = ans;`

Comment: I did this and still no luck with it: `<script language="javascript">
function multiply() {
var ans = parseFloat(document.form.myNumber.value);

ans = (ans * 0.035) + ans

document.getElementById("sum_total").value = ans;
}

</script>`

Comment: I've managed to do something else. but I will need to convert the value of an input field to 3.5% and everything should work.... any ideas how to convert a value of lets say `perc input field` into percentage?